# Debezium Mongo Connector can't read oplog, even using changestream

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I need to implement a CDC pattern but can't manage to make it work : my debezium worker is up and running, but my connectors still fail, despite my efforts.

I've tested a simple "watch" on my mongo cluster and it works :

```
watchCursor = db.mydb.watch()
while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
   if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
      print(watchCursor.next());
   }
}
```

So, i can tell that my user has rights on the clusters to watch changestreams.

I still have an error when running my tasks :

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "state": "FAILED",
        "worker_id": "10.114.129.247:8083",
        "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:42)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:115)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while attempting to get oplog position\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:85)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.doSnapshot(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:153)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:135)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:108)\n\t... 5 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while attempting to get oplog position\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.lambda$establishConnectionToPrimary$3(MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:234)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ConnectionContext$MongoPrimary.execute(ConnectionContext.java:292)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.lambda$determineSnapshotOffsets$6(MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:295)\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:976)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ReplicaSets.onEachReplicaSet(ReplicaSets.java:115)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.determineSnapshotOffsets(MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:290)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.doExecute(MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:99)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.doExecute(MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:52)\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:76)\n\t... 8 more\nCaused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized on local to execute command { find: \"oplog.rs\", filter: {}, sort: { $natural: -1 }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: \"local\", lsid: { id: UUID(\"de332d4a-32ec-424f-ae09-b32376444d11\") }, $readPreference: { mode: \"primaryPreferred\" } }' on server rc1a-REDACTED.mdb.yandexcloud.net:27018\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:663)\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:653)\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:583)\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:653)\n\tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)\n\tat com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:184)\n\tat com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:200)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.lambda$determineSnapshotOffsets$5(MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:297)\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ConnectionContext$MongoPrimary.execute(ConnectionContext.java:288)\n\t... 15 more\n"
    }
]
```

Simply said, i do not have rights on oplog.rs. Despite i'm not using oplog, but "changestream".

Here is my configuration

```
{
"name": "account3-connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
    "mongodb.password": "REDACTED",
    "transforms": "unwrap,idToKey,extractIdKey",
    "capture.mode": "change_streams_update_full",
    "collection.include.list": "account.account",
    "mongodb.ssl.enabled": "false",
    "transforms.idToKey.fields": "id",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "transforms.extractIdKey.field": "id",
    "database.include.list": "account",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "mongodb.hosts": "rc1a-REDACTED.mdb.yandexcloud.net:27018,rc1b-REDACTED.mdb.yandexcloud.net:27018,rc1c-REDACTED.mdb.yandexcloud.net:27018",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "transforms.idToKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "mongodb.user": "debezium",
    "mongodb.name": "loyalty.raw.last",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "name": "account3-connector",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "transforms.extractIdKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key"
},
"tasks": [],
"type": "source"
}
```

Do any of you have an idea ? What could be wrong ?

I'm using Debezium 1.8.1 on Confluent base image 6.2.0

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0
```

Comment: have you found the solution?

AFAIK oplog & change stream is the method debezium will use. both still need oplog to ensure data integrity, cmiiw please, im new to debezium also

Answer (score 0):

I've run in to the same problem. I don't have a fix, but it seems that during initialization the connector tries to query the oplog even when using change streams.

This is the full stack trace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 with name 'Unauthorized' and error message 'not authorized on local to execute command { find: \"oplog.rs\", filter: {}, sort: { $natural: -1 }, limit: 1, singleBatch: true, $db: \"local\", lsid: { id: UUID(\"51399eae-bb7a-4706-b35c-048e878d23a8\") }, $readPreference: { mode: \"primaryPreferred\" } }' on server pl-0-westeurope-azure.pi8eh.mongodb.net:1025
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$1(FindOperation.java:699)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$2(OperationHelper.java:566)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:591)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$3(OperationHelper.java:565)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:591)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:564)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.lambda$execute$2(FindOperation.java:690)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:65)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:722)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:213)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoUtil.getOplogEntry(MongoUtil.java:236)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$initializeOffsets$4(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:306)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ConnectionContext$MongoPrimary.execute(ConnectionContext.java:317)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$initializeOffsets$5(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:977)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.ReplicaSets.onEachReplicaSet(ReplicaSets.java:120)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.initializeOffsets(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:300)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:89)
    at io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:51)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:174)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:141)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The [MongoUtil.getOplogEntry](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/main/debezium-connector-mongodb/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mongodb/MongoUtil.java#L233-L247) method is called which queries the "oplog.rs" collection from the "local" database.
My guess is that the user does not have permission to perform this query.

I don't which permission is required, or if it is possible to skip this step somehow.

From the documentation, it seems that [adding permission to read the oplog](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/atlas-oplog/) should fix the problem, but I have not confirmed this yet.

Answer (score 0):

December 2023 I still have this error, debezium runs but it does not display the topic on Kafka UI, I visited the debezium community to ask this problem, you can see it [here](https://debezium.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/348106-community-mongodb/topic/Authentication.20failed.20when.20using.20mongodb.20debezium.20connector/near/405619432)

In that link, you can solve this problem by using Mongodb connector from [their homepage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/configuration-properties/mongodb-connection/#mongodb-source-connection-properties), but it will expose your password on Kafka UI or any other platform.

Edit 06/12/2023: I solved the problem based on the user's answer above and a few links below:

- [Setup MongoDB](https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors/blob/master/docs/content/connectors/mongodb-cdc.md#availability)
- [See 4.7 Permission Control](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/598911)